# Confusion about using induction to check if a sequence is increasing

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation, solution-verification

> I'm told to show that the recursive sequence $a_1=1$,$a_n=\left( \frac{a^3_{n-1}+4a_{n-1}}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is increasing for $n \geq 2$.

The base case is trivial. $a_1=1$ and $a_2=\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ so obviously, $a_2 > a_1$.

For the induction hypothesis, $a_k > a_{k-1}$ for all $n=k$.

And then for the induction step. I start like so:

$a_k>a_{k-1}$

$a^3_k>a^3_{k-1}$

$a^3_k+4a_k>a^3_{k-1}+4a_{k-1}$

And I just finish building it up. Trivial.

But problem is that I just added $4a_k$ and $4a_{k-1}$ to both sides. So I added different quantities to both sides. I'm not really sure if I am allowed to do that.

If I can't do that, how would I proceed?

> For part b), I have to show that $1\leq a_n\leq3$.

Again, the Base case is trivial. Obviously $1\leq 1\leq3$.

For the induction hypothesis $1\leq a_k\leq3$ for all $n=k$.

But then for the induction step, I  run into the same problem.

$1\leq a_k \leq 3$

$1 \leq a^3_k \leq 27$

$1+4a_k \leq a^3_k + 4a_k \leq 27+4a_k$

I could keep going but both sides of the inequality don't match up with the original sequence. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong, if anything.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to add two inequalities if they point the same direction.

Suppose $a>b$ and $c>d$.
Then $a+c>b+c$ (added $c$ to the first inequality) and $b+c>b+d$ (added $b$ to the second).
Combining them you get $a+c>b+d$.
Basically, each term on the left is greater than the corresponding term on the right, so the sum on the left is also greater than the sum on the right.

For part b you have:
$$1+4a_k \leq a^3_k + 4a_k \leq 27+4a_k$$
You can use the inequalities from the induction to remove the $a_k$ term from the outside expressions:
$$ 27+4a_k \leq 27+4\cdot3 = 39$$
and
$$ 5 = 1+4\cdot 1 \leq 1+4a_k$$
which gives you
$$\frac52 \leq \frac{a^3_k + 4a_k}2 \leq \frac{39}2$$
and since the cube root is an increasing function, you get
$$\left(\frac52\right)^{1/3} \leq \left(\frac{a^3_k + 4a_k}2\right)^{1/3} \leq \left(\frac{39}2\right)^{1/3}$$
and the result follows.

Comment: Yes thank you :) . That makes sense.